# Solaris/Unix equivalent of Event Log

Tags: unix, solaris, logging

What is the unix equivalent of the Windows Event Log - the tool that logs all processes that start and stop.

Need not be exact - with the whole GUI and everything. Anything close would do.

Answer (score 4):

This is different for Solaris/Linux:

- Solaris 10: `/var/svc/log/svc.startd.log`
- Linux: `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`*

*Although most daemons have their own logfiles in /var/log/daemonname/ for example.

Answer (score 3):

the `/var/log` directory is where almost all logs end up. There are graphical tools around to read them, though almost all are admin-friendly text.

Answer (score 0):

There is auditd which included many informations like ... who execute what.
Also there is syslogd / syslog-ng / **rsyslog** whcih is being used to monitor syslog event and parse / make actions based on some rules (These rules usually are located on /etc/rsyslog.d or /etc/rsyslog.conf {similar /etc/auditd.conf}).

For GUI you could use logzilla or splunk as free frameworks. (Of course there are many many others)

Answer (score 0):

auditd would do your audits (but you will need to configure this).  Additionally your "equivilent" of Event Log would ultimately be syslog-ng, which replaces most syslog on most Linux/Unix systems.  Furthermore, there is a utility called logrotate on Linux systems that allows you to rotate out your log files on a time/size basis, highly configurable.